# Why hooks of Vue 3 in WebStorm are grey out (Unused function created)

Tags: webstorm, vuejs3

As on the screenshot, a lot of hooks are grey and I don't know what the problem is. I don't get the problem for Vue 2 but for Vue 3.

[image: Hook are grey]

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known issue, please follow [WEB-38671](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38671) and linked tickets for updates

I can only suggest suppressing the inspection per instructions in [help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.3/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-inspections)